# memcache slows down joomla site

Tags: caching, joomla, memcached

I have been trying to enable memcache caching for my joomla site but all page loads are really slow. 
What should I check to troubleshoot this issue. I'm using joomla 2.5.6 php 5.3

Comment: Whatever the problem I would stop using memcache now. It has been removed from Apache 2.4 so you'll have to do that soon anyway.

Comment: Are you using an conservative or progressive caching model? How did you set "Persistent Memcache"?

Answer (score 1):

Memcache is slow with Joomla 2.5. The short answer is: use memcache**d** PHP module, not memcache.

Long answer: https://www.cloudaccess.net/about-us/blog/entry/2013/07/30/is-memcache-slowing-down-your-joomla-site.html